# How can i get a variable in another page?

Tags: php, mysql

Its not just a variable, the situation's like this:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());
mysql_select_db("tHofbrouwerijke") or die(mysql_error());
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM bieren";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) 
    {echo "<form action='RemoveBier.php' method='POST'><button type='submit' name=".$row['Naam'].">Verwijderen</button> &nbsp &nbsp".$row['Naam']."<br>";}
echo "</form>";
?>
```

so I used a while loop to get items from a database, and I want to use the name of the button to identify which item I have to delete. When I go to the page 'RemoveBier.php' and type in the code i think is right and try it, it does nothing. My second php page looks like this:

```
<?php 
include 'DeleteBier.php';
$NameButton=$row['Naam'];
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());
mysql_select_db("tHofbrouwerijke") or die(mysql_error());
echo $row['Naam'];
$strSQL = "DELETE FROM bieren WHERE naam = '.$_POST[$NameButton].'";
mysql_query($strSQL) or die(mysql_error());
header('Location: DeleteBier.php');
?>
```

Comment: Try `WHERE naam = '.$_POST[NameButton].'";` without the `$` or `WHERE naam = '" . $NameButton ."' ";`

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d. Plus your form generation code is bad. You're creating `<form><form><form></form>`: opening MULTIPLE forms, but closing only once.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="Beer2delete" value="SOME BEERS NAME HERE" />
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

You now have access to the name with `$_POST['Beer2delete']`. Users wont see it and you have a consistent name to refer to.

if you have multiple options, you can do it this way:

```
<form method="post">
    <!-- HERE YOU LOOP, but the radiobutton so it will result in the following -->
    <input type="radio" name="beer2delete" value="beer 1" /> Beer 1 <br />
    <input type="radio" name="beer2delete" value="beer 2" /> Beer 2 <br />
    <input type="radio" name="beer2delete" value="beer 3" /> Beer 3 <br />
    <input type="radio" name="beer2delete" value="beer 4" /> Beer 4 <br />

    <input type="submit" name="DeleteBeer" value="Delete that delicious beer"/>
</form>
```

Comment: `<button>Submit</button>` ? You've gone this far, why not make it an actual input button?

Comment: Wouldn't work if an `if(isset...` is used, which is better to have ;-)

Comment: I've changed it to an input, with a name for easier reference, which should make the code a bit more flexible, thanks